# How many cells will have finite values

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I encountered one programming question.

Consider I have N cells.These cells can have some integer value or expression.
There can be T number of iterations.In every iteration ,some cells can be updated.
In every iteration ,I have to tell how many cells have finite value(which can be determined).

For example, if N=5,then five cells can be A,B,C,D,E.
Suppose following are the values 
A=4, B=D+E, C=2*B, D=6, E=A+B
So,In this case only two cells(A and D) have finite values 4 and 6 respectively.Value of B ,C and E cannot be determined.B depends on E which in turn depends on B(cyclic direct dependency). C on the other hand depends on B which is undetermined.

Suppose,now I update B to 10 instead of D+E, then all the cells have finite value . A(4),B(10),C(20),D(6),E(14).In each iteration value of a cell can be changed.

Constraints:(1'<'N<=200, 1<'T'<=1000)

What I tried:Make dependency list for every cell.For each iteration update that dependency list.If it contains any one element which is undetermined,then for this iteration,this cell cannot have finite value.
Is there any other better approach?

Comment: What if A = 2*B and B = A - 3? There is a unique solution A=6, B=3 in spite of the cyclic reference.

Comment: Which way the dependency list goes? Also how do you do recursive updates?

Comment: Dependency can go either way.It is possible that all cells are undetermined.

Comment: I mean, if A depends on B, do you store it in A or in B?

Comment: Every cell has an expression.So if A depends on B ,it will be stored in A

Answer (score 0):

Instinctively, I'd go all the way and build a proper dependency graph. This is a directed graph, a node has edges to other nodes if it depends on them.

When updating a node, we just destroy its outbound edges and rebuild them as neccessary. The actual calculation: from each node, we start a depth-first traversal that terminates when a node marked as "known" is encountered, then starts propagating the mark backwards: that is, we mark a node as "known" if all of its child nodes are marked as such.

I think this is basically the same as your solution. Depending on the actual implementation, this may have better runtime performance, and I think it's a visually cleaner solution.

Regarding @Henry's comment:

> What if A = 2*B and B = A - 3? There is a unique solution A=6, B=3 in
>   spite of the cyclic reference.

We could introduce an optimisation step after update. We could check for cycles, and if we've found one, we could try to resolve it by solving the system of equations. That'd be cool.